# Can I transfer existing boards to newly created organizations?

Tags: trello

Is it possible on Trello to add existing boards to newly created organizations, or change them to another organization?

I can't seem to find the button.

Answer (score 2):

If you own the existing board, and are a member of the target organization then you can

1. Go to the board
2. Click **Options**
3. Click **Settings**
4. Click **Change Organization**